# Parsing json output retrieved from an API using Ansbile

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

I am new to Ansible. I am trying to fetch some API info from a centralized server in the json format, parse the json and set "**certificate**" to "**yes**" for each and every server and make a PUT operation back. GET and PUT operations in my code are working fine.

**I am not able to find correct syntax to parse listofservers.json.**
**What is the syntax to display a specific json element??**

Can you help me on how to parse the json to change "Certificate" value to Yes for all the servers?

**My script**

```
- hosts: serverlist

vars_prompt:
- name: "USER"
  prompt: "Enter Admin Username"
  private: no
- name: "PASS"
  prompt: "Enter Admin Password"
  private: yes

  tasks:
- name: "Get the current values of all Servers"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: listofservers
  check_mode: no


  uri:
    validate_certs: "no"
    user: "{{USER}}"
    password: "{{PASS}}"
    url: "https://console.exmaple.com/adminapi/serverlist"
    method: "GET"
    body_format: "json"
    return_content: "no"
    status_code: "200"

- name: Print json dictionary
  debug:
    var: listofservers.json
```

**Output**

```
TASK [Print json dictionary] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [centalServer.example.com] =>
{
"listofservers.json": {
   "serverlist": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "servername": "redhat.example.com",
  "apachestatus": "running",
  "certificate": "no"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "servername": "solaris.example.com",
  "apachestatus": "down",
  "certificate": "yes"
}  ] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Change "certificate" value to "yes" for all servers.*"**

A: The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        listofservers: "{{ {'json':
                           {'serverlist': serverlist}} }}"
      vars:
        serverlist: "{{ listofservers.json.serverlist|
                        map('combine', {'certificate': 'yes'})|
                        list }}"
    - debug:
        var: listofservers.json
```

give

```yaml
{
    "listofservers.json": {
        "serverlist": [
            {
                "apachestatus": "running",
                "certificate": "yes",
                "id": 1,
                "servername": "redhat.example.com"
            },
            {
                "apachestatus": "down",
                "certificate": "yes",
                "id": 2,
                "servername": "solaris.example.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

Q: **"*What is the syntax to display a specific JSON element?*"**

A: There are two main options 1) [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) and 2) [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries), and many variations which depend on the structure of the data and requested query

For example, display first *servername* where *id* is equal to 1

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ listofservers.json.serverlist|
                 selectattr('id', 'eq', 1)|
                 map(attribute='servername')|
                 first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "redhat.example.com"
```

The same result will give *json_query* below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ listofservers.json.serverlist|
                 json_query('[?id == `1`].servername')|
                 first }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I really appreciate you taking time to reply to my query. It didn't resolve the issue. It throws below error TASK [set_fact] ******
fatal: [centalServer.example.com]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:
An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ listofservers.json.serverlist| map('combine', {'certificate': 'yes'})| list }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ listofservers.json.serverlist| map('combine', {'certificate': 'yes'})| list }}): 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: To make it ease, I had pasted trimmed down version of json file. Can you tell me What is the syntax to display a specific json element?? This should really help me as I need to put in few more logic in my code. I tried below code to print servername but went in vain.    - name: "Print Single element"
      debug:
        var: "{{ listofservers.json.serverlist.servername}}"

Comment: `serverlist` is, as its name suggest, a list. Hence `listofservers.json.serverlist.servername` does not exists, but you can access `listofservers.json.serverlist.0.servername` or `listofservers.json.serverlist.1.servername`... You can also loop over that list to go through each item.

Comment: @John: open a new question if you have other issues. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).